# Changing default text on Thank You Screen

Tags: registration

My company uses thank you screens for event registrations. The screen has this text on a green background: "Your registration has been submitted. Once your registration has been reviewed, you will receive an email with a link to a web page where you can complete the registration process."

We don't use the built-in 'web page where you can complete the registration process' and really want to replace this text, but I can't see where to do that. Can anyone help?

Related to this, the 'introductory text' field on the thank you screen never seems to work.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain a bit more "We don't use the built-in 'web page" - what are you using?

Comment: What CMS are you using?

Comment: petednz: we don't make participants complete the registration process with a second link, we just send them an email to confirm their place at the event. 
//
Iowa Boy: Wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick update: this issue seems to have sorted itself out, possibly with one of the recent CiviCRM updates. Not the most helpful answer for anyone with a similar issue, but this appears to be fixed for me now.

Answer (score 1):

Try Word replacement (more like sentence replacement) in your case. Here is a how to:

https://www.cividesk.com/blog/did-you-know-any-word-or-phrase-civicrm-can-be-replaced-another-one

Comment: Sounded promising! But doesn't appear to work...

Comment:  I definitively am using sentence replacement for a client on an event registration..

Comment: Can you point me to a page on http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org where I can see the text you're trying to replace?

Comment: Howdy. It's the stuff in the green box at the top of this page, assuming the link works: http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/event/register?_qf_ThankYou_display=true&qfKey=f8d496b8ab1c91e53d693d8cad740345_8502

I can see that the text in the green box has been replaced from the default, so I do trust you that it's possible! but when I try to do word replacement it won't change.

Here's a link to one of our own events if you want to see the text I'm trying to replace (can do a dummy registration): http://futureoflondon.org.uk/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/event/info&reset=1&id=170

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `hook_civicrm_postProcess` hook and put the check for target event registration page and form name to be for the thank you screen. `$form` values can be changed using this hook.